# Making absolute section

Tags: html, css

I made a navbar and sections but when i try to make center section absolute, it gets ahead of my navbar. I want centersection to stay just between the other sections not behind or ahead of navbar.

```css
.left-section {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: $color-primary;
}

.center-section {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background-color: $color-primary;
  left: 30%;
  width: 40%;
}

.right-section {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background-color: $color-primary;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-container">
  <div class="left-section t-aside">

  </div>
  <div class="center-section">

  </div>
  <div class="right-section t-aside">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want a grid, use a grid. Absolute positioning is a niche tool that isn't good at large scale layout.

Comment: @Quentin but when i do display grid the aside sections break the other way if i use grid positioning all of the sections when i set fixed it goes the same situation like i sent above

Comment: The position of absolute element is relative to the closest ancestor with relative position. Also it is out of the normal flow and no space are allocated for element with absolute position. Use top, bottom, right, left to choose the position and add relative position to t-container. this link could help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position but using flex layout is better in this case as Kameron answer said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay away from using `position: fixed;` or `absolute;` unless it's **absolutely** needed. In the case of your navbar, `flex` does the job well.

```css
.t-container {
  outline: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-section,
.center-section,
.right-section {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.center-section {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="t-container">
  <div class="left-section t-aside">
    nav1
  </div>
  <div class="center-section">
    nav2
  </div>
  <div class="right-section t-aside">
    nav3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreaciate your answer and is there any way to make left and right section constant

Comment: @eErgun what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: when i scroll the page down i want left and right section to stay at the same position. Actually I'm thinking about put advertisements to there.

Comment: @eErgun Like this? [A Fiddle for eErgun](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/canhb9g4/1/)

Comment: Appreciate your effort, I made it